# Measuring the uncertainty of points along a trajectory

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, gaussian-process, uncertainty

I have a number of 2D trajectories, and I want to be able to estimate the variance of each step along the mean trajectory. I thought that this might be suited to Gaussian process modelling, but then I realised that this may not work...

So, my understanding of a Guassian process is that predictions of one variable (e.g. y) are made conditional on another variable (e.g. x), but where that prediction has an uncertainty for all values of x. So for this 2D (x, y) example, the prediction may look like this: (please excuse the terrible drawing!)
[image]

However, in my case, the data is actually drawn from a trajectory through space. (x, y) are just points in Euclidean 2D space. I now want to fit a distribution to this data, so that I can estimate the uncertainty at each step along the trajectory. This may look something like this:

[image]

But if I were to just train a regular Gaussian process on this data, it would probably end up looking like this:

[image]

What kind of technique should I be using to fit the distribution I am looking for? Is a Gaussian process suitable? Or some other method?

My overall aim is to be able to take any step along the trajectory, and estimate the variance of the data points at this step of the trajectory. I am not actually concerned with making predictions; I just want to estimate this uncertainty.

Answer (score 3):

The trick here is that you want to parameterize your trajectory so that it is a function of time. In your case the trajectory is $\theta(t) : t \to \mathbb{R}^2$. This is also implicit in the way you phrased the question you want to answer, since you want to estimate the variance of the trajectory at a particular "step" (time).

Gaussian processes have recently been receiving a lot of attention in the context of robot motion planning. I know Byron Boots has been working a lot in this area, for more formal treatments/ideas see [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.07383.pdf) and his [google scholar](https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&user=kXB8FBoAAAAJ&view_op=list_works&sortby=pubdate#) page.